How to make bat file for open URL
I'm trying to get a bat file to open specific URL.
I'm trying to make the bat file to open around 4 to 5 different websites to make my work faster.
I tried in notepad the following:
@echo off
start opera http://websitename.com

but after I ran it, it just keeps opening 100s of prompt windows.

wait - did you name your script opera.bat or opera.cmd? Don't.

It is always a very bad idea giving a script file like a batch file the name of a Windows command or of an executable like Opera.exe. You have learned now why this is a very bad idea and why it is good to specify an executable with its file extension .exe (or .com) and why it is best using the fully qualified file name, i. e. drive + path + name + extension enclosed in " on containing a space or one of these characters &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~.

I hope the batch file contains more than just these two lines as otherwise the usage of a batch file to start Opera with a specific URL is the worst method which exists at all for doing that. It would be much better using a shortcut file for that task which can be created with a few mouse clicks and then modified for appending the URL to the Target property of the shortcut. I suppose there is already an Opera shortcut on your desktop. Copy and paste it on your desktop, right click on the copy and click on Properties and append the URL on Target. That's it.

You could create a BAT file like this:
@echo off
start "" https://www.example.com
start "" https://www.another-site.com

Then will be open with your default browser.

start "" https://www.example.com — that empty title string is surprisingly important

On Windows 10 work both versions

As long as you have no quotes anywhere else in the start command, the empty title quotes are optional. As soon as you quote anything else, they become mandatory. It's a good idea to get into the habit of adding them even when you don't need them so that you build the muscle memory and don't get burned later.

@SomethingDark I understood. Fixed

Thank you all for responding, i tried it they way you guys advised:
@echo off
start "" https://www.example.com

and it worked like a charm i am very thankful. You guys have a great day.

Instead of posting this answer, please click the check mark next to Nifriz's answer to mark it as accepted.
